# Return statement inside if, else if, else statement is not working

Tags: java

I stumbled on some issue in my codes, supposedly a return will stop my method but in my case isn't. I tried to make a method called "binarySearch" which supposedly do what its made to do.

```
public int binarySearch(int lowIndex, int highIndex, int[] arr, int val) {
    int middleIndex = (lowIndex + highIndex ) / 2;
    if(arr[middleIndex] < val) {
        lowIndex = middleIndex;
    } else if (arr[middleIndex] > val) {
        highIndex = middleIndex;
    } else {
        return middleIndex;
    }
    binarySearch(lowIndex, highIndex, arr, val);
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is if I already found the index where the search value reside else statement will return it and stop already. but instead, I always get "0", which is I think the value i set for default return `return 0`. so for some clarification, I added some text on my else statement to make sure it executed and return `middleIndex`, then the text showed up so basically my loop enters else statement and hopefully returned `middleIndex` but its not. maybe recursion has to do with this but I don't know maybe you guys can help me.

Comment: You don't return the result of your recursion.

Comment: i'm not familiar with recursion can you modify the codes to make it work? because i know i did return it through else statement and for what i know the recursion stops there hehe thx

Comment: You return it from your else, but then ignore it on this line: `binarySearch(lowIndex, highIndex, arr, val);`

Comment: `binarySearch` is calling itself with the **same arguments** that were passed to it. How is this ever producing anything other than an infinite loop and eventual stack overflow exception?

Comment: @KevinAnderson no it's not calling itself with the same arguments. It either returns the found index (else case) or modifies either `lowIndex` (if case) or the `highIndex` (else if case) before calling itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the signature of your method says `public int binarySearch`, that means you should return the int from the recursive call of `binarySearch` method. You shouldn't really `return 0` in a proper implementation of this method.

Comment: thanks mate, you explained whats wrong to my codes and did a hint how to do it. upvoting for that.

Comment: @YihangWang The risk you run when writing pretty much any recursive function in Java, it's unlikely to actually be a problem for the op.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the result of your recursion. You can refer to this code shown below to understand what you are doing wrong.

```
  // Returns index of x if it is present in arr[l..
    // r], else return -1
    int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
    {
        if (r>=l)
        {
            int mid = l + (r - l)/2;

            // If the element is present at the 
            // middle itself
            if (arr[mid] == x)
               return mid;

            // If element is smaller than mid, then 
            // it can only be present in left subarray
            if (arr[mid] > x)
               return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);

            // Else the element can only be present
            // in right subarray
            return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
        }

        // We reach here when element is not present
        //  in array
        return -1;
    }
```

For more information regarding BinarySearch and its implementation you can follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/) link

Comment: thanks for the help mate but i can only choose 1 answer thanks by the way :)

Comment: Ofcourse you can choose the best answer. Upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Here is iterative java code for Binary Search, yours is somewhat flawed.

```
int binarySearch(int arr[], int x) {
    int l = 0, r = arr.length - 1;

    while (l <= r) {

        int m = l + (r-l)/2;

        if (arr[m] == x)
            return m;

        if (arr[m] < x)
            l = m + 1;

        else
            r = m - 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks mate but swapnil explained whats wrong to my codes why i pick his answer, thanks by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void binarySearch(int arr[], int first, int last, int key){  
   int mid = (first + last)/2;  
   while( first <= last ){  
      if ( arr[mid] < key ){  
        first = mid + 1;     
      }else if ( arr[mid] == key ){  
        System.out.println("Element is found at index: " + mid);  
        break;  
      }else{  
         last = mid - 1;  
      }  
      mid = (first + last)/2;  
   }  
   if ( first > last ){  
      System.out.println("Element is not found!");  
   }
```

you can do it by recursion also.

Answer (score 0):

There are minor mistakes in your code.

In recursion, when a function recursively calls itself, the function call should be placed in a return statement. This makes sure that the result of the recursive function calls is returned to calling function.

Here is the modified code -

```
class BinarySearch
{
    // Returns index of x if it is present in arr[l..
    // r], else return 0

    public int binarySearch(int lowIndex, int highIndex, int[] arr, int val) 
    {
        if(highIndex>=lowIndex)  //this line should be added for safety
        {
            int middleIndex = (lowIndex + highIndex ) / 2;
            if(arr[middleIndex] < val) 
            {
                lowIndex = middleIndex;
            } 
            else if (arr[middleIndex] > val) 
            {
                highIndex = middleIndex;
            } 
            else 
            {
                return middleIndex;
            }
            return binarySearch(lowIndex, highIndex, arr, val);  //this should be the return statement
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Driver method to test above
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BinarySearch ob = new BinarySearch();
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        int n = arr.length;
        int x = 7;
        int result = ob.binarySearch(0,n-1,arr,x);
        if (result == 0)
            System.out.println("Element not present");
        else
            System.out.println("Element found at index " + result);
    }
}
```

This code works fine.

Recursive stack explanation for the above code-

binarySearch(0,7,arr,val)

= return (binarySearch(3,7,arr,val))

= return (return (binarySearch(5,7,arr,val)))

= return (return (return 6))  //here 6 is the middleValue that is returned in else block

= return (return 6)

= return 6

Since, you didnt add the return statement in your code, your topmost function call in the recursive stack was returning 0.